# Synchroized RSS over Tor

Tags: anonymity

I am currently using a Feedly account without Tor to synchronize my RSS reading on multiple devices. Is there any solution to achieve this synchronization (possibly without Feedly account) over Tor?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but the amount of telemetry and other information that comes with using a proprietary syncing solution like Feedly makes it impossible to do anonymously without revealing your real IP to the Feedly servers. To begin with, I would recommend using a more privacy-conscious open-source solution (maybe something self-hosted would be a good start) and then start using Tor for it.